# how can I use leanft on existing java automation framework

Tags: java, leanft

I have an existing java automation framework for Ibm's Rational RFT. We have decided to move to HP UFT as there needs to be BPT implemented for a SAP application. We are loathe to recode the java framework into .vbs and thought LeanFT might make it possible to use most of the existing java code. Can anyone give me an idea how to do so (I am attaching some of the code)

```
package Runner.CMS;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import resources.Runner.CMS.AccessIntegration_TestRunnerHelper;
import utils.TestData;

import com.rational.test.ft.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.SAP.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.siebel.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.flex.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.script.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.value.*;
import com.rational.test.ft.vp.*;


/**
  * Description   : Functional Test Script for IPR (Sydney Water)
  * @author Simmer
*/
public class AccessIntegration_TestRunner extends       AccessIntegration_TestRunnerHelper
{
    /**
     * Script Name   : <b>PaymentArrangement_TestRunner</b>
     * Generated     : <b>12/02/2014 4:47:58 PM</b>
     * Description   : Functional Test Script
     * Original Host : WinNT Version 6.1  Build 7601 (S)
     * 
     * @since  2014/02/12
     * @author Simmer
     * @throws Exception 
     */
     public void testMain(Object[] args) throws Exception 
     {

    setProjectName("Access Integration");
    setProjectDescription("CMS Access Integration Automated Test Suite");
    setExecutionDetails("CMS_");
    setDatapoolFolder("\\Datapools\\CMS\\AccessIntegration\\");
    setTestFlowFilename("AccessIntegration_TestFlow.xls");
    setExpectedResultsFilename("AccessIntegration_ExpectedResults.xls");
    setExecutionReportsFolder("\\ExecutionReports\\CMS\\AccessIntegration\\");
    setExecutionResultsFolder("\\ExecutionResults\\CMS\\AccessIntegration\\");
    setScreenCaptureLevel(3);
    setEnvironment("CTE1");


    isOfficialRun(false);
    run();
}
```

}

Comment: record java framework into .vbs **or** use leanft with IBM Rational RFT? looks to me like two separate questions